# How to connect Firebase service account to different GCP project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I want to use the `Firebase Admin SDK`. And I will deploy my server into the `GKE`. but apparently, when clicking 'service account' from my firebase, it is linked to another 'project' in my `GCP`

To give an example of it, my whole project in GCP is under a project **'project-a'** with an ID of ***'project-a-12345678'***.
my firebase project name is **'project-b'** with and id of ***'project-b'***.

So how can I connect my firebase to my current GKE's project service account?

Comment: Firebase projects *are* Google Cloud projects that just have some extra metadata attached to them. Are you saying that you want to access your Firebase project from a GKE in a different Google Cloud project? If so, that is definitely possible, but things will be (a bit) simpler if you run the GKE in the same project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen im also ok to put it into the same project, but how can I put it into the same project? how can I change my firebase to use the same project as my current GKE? since when I check my firebase setting, I cant edit my project ID

Comment: That's the opposite of what I said, but should be possible too. :)
If you go to the [Firebase console])https://console.firebase.google.com/), click `Add project` and then click in the `Enter your project name` box, it'll show you a list of GCP project that you have that are not associated with Firebase. If you select one of those project, it add the Firebase metadata and you can then use Firebase services on it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase projects *are* Google Cloud projects, that just have some extra metadata attached to them. If you have an existing Firebase project, you can use GKE in that same project by opening it in the Google Cloud console.

You can also go the other direction and add Firebase features to an existing Google Cloud project. For this, go to the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), click <kbd>Add project</kbd> and then click in the <kbd>Enter your project name</kbd> box, it'll show you a list of GCP project that you have that are not associated with Firebase. If you select one of those project, it add the Firebase metadata and you can then use Firebase services on it too.

Comment: thank you. gladly I havent go live yet, so I can re create my firebase project. this is more make sense than moving my GKE. since in GKE, there are a lot lot of configs (ex networking, firewall, etc) that have been done